# Name of theorem: bounds on components of a sum of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Given two non-zero vectors $u$ and $v$ and two scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ one can show that

$$\lVert \alpha u + \beta v \rVert
\ge
\lVert \alpha u \rVert
\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\lvert u\cdot v \rvert^2}{{\lVert u \rVert}^2 {\lVert v \rVert}^2}\right)}
$$
So that when $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent we have

$$\lVert \alpha u \rVert
\le
\frac{\lVert \alpha u + \beta v \rVert}
{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\lvert u\cdot v\rvert^2}{{\lVert u \rVert}^2 {\lVert v \rVert}^2}\right)}} 
$$

I can prove this by showing that $\lVert u + \lambda v\rVert$ is minimized for 
$$\lambda = -\frac{u \cdot v}{\lVert v \rVert^2}$$

But is doing so necessary? My question is whether the inequality above is a named theorem or a simple corollary of a named theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will be helpful: Notice that it suffices to show
$$
\lVert u + v \rVert
\ge
\lVert u \rVert
\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\lvert u\cdot v \rvert^2}{{\lVert u \rVert}^2 {\lVert v \rVert}^2}\right)}
$$
since you can then replace $u$ by $\alpha u$ and $v$ by $\beta v$ if you like. If $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $u$ and $v$, then $u\cdot v = \|u\||v\|\cos \theta$, and therefore the above inequality is equivalent to
$$
\|u+v\| \ge \|u\| \cdot |\!\sin\theta|.
$$
And this can be proved geometrically (draw the vector $u$, the line $\{u+\lambda v\colon \lambda\in\Bbb R\}$, and the vector from the origin that is perpendicular to that line and exactly long enough to reach it). So I don't know what the name of this inequality is, but it's basically a fact from geometry.

Comment: Perhaps it follows just from **law of sines**: $\frac{\|u+v\|}{|\!\sin\theta|} = \frac{\|u\|}{|\!\sin\gamma|} \geq \|u\|$, unless I am missing something.